# Disable Responsiveness For Twitter Bootsrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

Since Bootstrap 3 has no seperate files for responsive and standards. So how can I easily disable the responsive features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Steps to disable page responsiveness**

1. Omit the viewport `<meta>` mentioned in the CSS docs
2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a single width, for example `width: 970px !important;` Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the `!important` with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

Hope this may useful

For Reference use this [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)